# Encountering error "#8 0.278 chmod: cannot access '/app/setup.sh': No such file or directory" in Docker with Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am facing an issue while using Docker in conjunction with Visual Studio 2022. The error message that I consistently encounter is:

> #8 0.278 chmod: cannot access '/app/setup.sh': No such file or directory

Despite my earnest efforts, I have not yet been able to discern the underlying cause of this problem or devise an effective solution.

I have confirmed that my Dockerfile, setup.sh, docker-compose.yml, and all related files are located within the same directory. Nonetheless, the problem persists and it seems that Docker is unable to access the 'setup.sh' file.

Could anyone kindly shed some light on this issue, or propose potential troubleshooting steps?

Error detail:

```
Severity Code    Description Project File Line    Suppression State
Error CTC1014 Docker command failed with exit code 1.
#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#1 transferring dockerfile: 309B done
#1 DONE 0.0s

#2 [internal] load .dockerignore
#2 transferring context: 382B done
#2 DONE 0.0s

#3 [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
#3 DONE 0.0s

#4 [1/5] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
#4 DONE 0.0s

#5 [internal] load build context
#5 transferring context: 182.67kB done
#5 DONE 0.0s

#6 [2/5] WORKDIR /app
#6 CACHED

#7 [3/5] COPY . .
#7 DONE 0.0s

#8 [4/5] RUN chmod +x /app/setup.sh
#8 0.278 chmod: cannot access '/app/setup.sh': No such file or directory
#8 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c chmod +x /app/setup.sh" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
------
 > [4 / 5] RUN chmod +x / app / setup.sh:
#8 0.278 chmod: cannot access '/app/setup.sh': No such file or directory
------
Dockerfile:7
--------------------
   5 | COPY. .
   6 | USER root
   7 | >>> RUN chmod + x / app / setup.sh
   8 | RUN(/ opt / mssql / bin / sqlservr & ) | grep - q "Service Broker manager has started" && / bin / bash./ setup.sh
   9 |
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c chmod +x /app/setup.sh" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1 DockerTest C:\Users\yiyang\Desktop\DockerTest\DockerTest\DockerTest\Dockerfile     1
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
WORKDIR /app
ENV ACCEPT_EULA= Y
ENV MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD = "CG*123cg"
COPY. .
USER root
RUN chmod +x /app/setup.sh
RUN (/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr & ) | grep - q "Service Broker manager has started" && / bin / bash./ setup.sh
```

setup.sh:

```
# !/bin/bash
/ opt / mssql / bin / sqlservr &
echo "Waiting for SQL Server to start..."
for i in { 1..50}; do
  / opt / mssql - tools / bin / sqlcmd - S localhost - U SA - P 'CG*123cg' - d master - Q 'SELECT 1;' > / dev / null 2 > &1
  if [ $? -eq 0]; then
    echo "SQL Server started."
    break
  else
        echo "Not ready yet..."
    sleep 1s
  fi
done
/ opt / mssql - tools / bin / sqlcmd - S localhost - U SA - P 'CG*123cg' - d master - Q 'CREATE DATABASE cgomnitransactional;'
/ opt / mssql - tools / bin / sqlcmd - S localhost - U SA - P 'CG*123cg' - d cgomnitransactional - i./ SchemaGenerationScript.sql
/ opt / mssql - tools / bin / sqlcmd - S localhost - U SA - P 'CG*123cg' - d cgomnitransactional - i./ DataGenerationScript.sql
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
sql_server:
build:
context: .
dockerfile: Dockerfile
environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
      MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD: "CG*123cg"
    ports:
-1433:1433
    volumes:
-sqlvolume:/ var / opt / mssql
volumes:
sqlvolume:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After persistent efforts and extensive research, the issue of Visual Studio being unable to locate the 'setup.sh' file has finally been resolved. The solution involved adding Docker Support to my project within Visual Studio. This was achieved by right-clicking the project name and selecting "Add" -> "Docker Support...". If Docker Support has already been added, the next step is to add "Container Orchestrator Support...". The auto-generated 'docker-compose.yml', 'docker-compose.override.yml', and 'docker-compose.dcproj' content was then replaced with my custom 'docker-compose.yml' content. Additionally, ensured that 'docker-compose' is set as the start-up project for consistent behavior.

docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  sql_server:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
      MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD: "CG*123cg"
    ports:
      - 1433:1433
    volumes:
      - sqlvolume:/var/opt/mssql
volumes:
  sqlvolume:
```

docker-compose.override.yml :

```
version: '3.4'
```

docker-compose.dcproj :

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding= "utf-8" ?>
< Project ToolsVersion = "15.0" Sdk= "Microsoft.Docker.Sdk" >
  < PropertyGroup Label= "Globals" >
    < ProjectVersion > 2.1 </ ProjectVersion >
    < DockerTargetOS > Linux </ DockerTargetOS >
    < ProjectGuid > 17bfe135-1fc2-4af9-8d7c-b9eb3bac24d9</ProjectGuid>
    <DockerLaunchAction>LaunchBrowser</DockerLaunchAction>
    <DockerServiceUrl>{ Scheme}://localhost:{ServicePort}</DockerServiceUrl>
    < DockerServiceName > dockertest </ DockerServiceName >
  </ PropertyGroup >
  < ItemGroup >
    < None Include = "docker-compose.override.yml" >
      < DependentUpon > docker - compose.yml </ DependentUpon >
    </ None >
    < None Include = "docker-compose.yml" />
    < None Include = ".dockerignore" />
  </ ItemGroup >
</ Project >
```